# Create subset of ranges and individual items

Tags: r, subset

I'm using R and have a dataset with ~3000 psychological test data. The data is all dyadic in male-female partners (though this shouldn't matter for you). I'm creating a new data frame with just the variables of interest, most of them are not sequentially listed in the original data so I select them by name like below:

```
new_df <- subset(data, select=c("MQ4", "FQ4", #RX STATUS
                               "MQ9", "FQ9", #ETHNICITY
                               "MQ10", "FQ10", #RACE
                               "MQ465", "FQ465", #SEX
                               "MQ13", "FQ13", #GENDER
                               "MQ14", "FQ14", #SEXORIENT
                               "MQ180", "MQ181", "MQ182", "MQ182" ### HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP
 ))
```

However, I have about 150 unique items that *are* listed sequentially and I'd like to select them without writing out "MQ180" through "MQ310" to select them all. I've been trying to figure out a way to select the range as well to the individual items I have been doing. This is currently what I'm trying:

```
new_df <- subset(data, select=c("MQ4", "FQ4", #RX STATUS
                               "MQ9", "FQ9", #ETHNICITY
                               "MQ10", "FQ10", #RACE
                               "MQ465", "FQ465", #SEX
                               "MQ13", "FQ13", #GENDER
                               "MQ14", "FQ14", #SEXORIENT
                               163:310         ### HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP
 ))
```

Comment: Whilst you have answers to your specific question, I *strongly* urge you to make your data frame [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) before proceeding.  A little extra work now will save you hours of grief and pain later on.

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
dplyr::select(mtcars, "cyl", 5:8)
```

This subsets the `mtcars` dataframe to just the `cyl` column and the 5th thru 8th column:

```
                    cyl drat    wt  qsec vs
Mazda RX4             6 3.90 2.620 16.46  0
Mazda RX4 Wag         6 3.90 2.875 17.02  0
Datsun 710            4 3.85 2.320 18.61  1
```

---

Here's a base R alternative but there's probably a better way:

```
cbind(mtcars[, 'cyl'],  mtcars[, 5:8])
```

---

mtcars originally:

```
                                          5     6     7  8 
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Even I got these on my first try! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the index part of `subset` `select` can use `names`

```
subset(data, select=c("MQ4", "FQ4", #RX STATUS
                               "MQ9", "FQ9", #ETHNICITY
                               "MQ10", "FQ10", #RACE
                               "MQ465", "FQ465", #SEX
                               "MQ13", "FQ13", #GENDER
                               "MQ14", "FQ14", #SEXORIENT
                               names(data)[163:310]         
 ))
```

The issue arises because of the property of `vector` which can only have a single `class`.  So, when we have both `character` and `integer`,  the integers are converted to `character` and thus it will look for column names that matches the name `"163"` instead of the position index

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the explanation for why my attempt wasn't working!